# Resizing a UIView so UIScrollView works

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a small form which I built mostly in interface builder:

[image]

When the user touches inside one of the textfields, I make the top part of the screen scrollable (note that it does not require any scrolling when the keyboard is not present, and that neither field is hidden behind the keyboard).

[image]

I achieve this with very little code.  My form controls are all inside a UIScrollView, which is disabled and sized 0x0 (by default) on load.  When I detect the keyboard's presence I enable it and resize it to the **views's width** and the **view's height + the keyboard size**.  I then disable and resize the scrollview when the keyboard is removed (I set it back to 0x0).

This works almost perfectly.  With one exception (so far):

The scrollable area (or rather, the view inside it) is too tall.  Because the form without the keyboard does not take up the whole screen, I find that I can scroll to the bottom of my view (one full screen) + keyboard height, when what I really want is to scroll to the view's **contents** + keyboard height.

I thought I could simply make the view shorter so that it is just the right size for the contents, but interface builder (xcode 4.2) seems to force it to take up the whole screen.  Attempting to do it in code also doesn't work, because apparently self.view.frame.size is not assignable.  How can I achieve what I'm looking for?  Specifically, when the keyboard is present, I want the scrollable area in the top half of the screen to be sized such that there isn't so much 'slack' at the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, self.view.frame is a struct with two fields that are structs itself - size and origin. If you want to change either size or origin, you have change the whole frame

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, 
    self.view.frame.size.width, <your desired height>);
```

Second, what base do use to create your form? This looks like just a UITableVIew. If so, consider changing type of your UIViewController to UITableViewController, since it handles keyboard automatically.

If neither is an option for you, provide the code you use when handling keyboard appearance, so that we could think of more concrete answer.

Comment: These are mostly UITextFields, just styled a little.  The bottom one, Department, is a tableview.

Comment: @BenPackard I think you should also try modifying contentSize property of your scrollView. It seems that you only change the frame of scrollView, but the contentSize leaves unchanged, and contentSize determines how much the content of scrollView will be scrolled.

Comment: Thanks.  So I am now manually forcing the view to be smaller on load using gavrix's answer and then when the keyboard pops out I am setting the content size. In both of these I am providing floats, which doesn't feel very reuseable but is working ok.  I have a small issue when I undo these changes - the view 'snaps' back instead of scrolling.  Working on that now.

Comment: @BenPackard to avoid this you should change frame with animation, take a look at what is provided in keyboard notification's userInfo - there are some animation parameters that system will use for keyboard's animation and which could be used in your animation.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look.  I noticed already that "Animation key/value pairs are only available for the "will" family of notification."  Currently I am listening for 'keyboard was shown' notes - should I switch to 'Keyboard Will Show' notes?  Are there any other side effects of making this change I might expect?

Comment: @BenPackard no other issues, and switching to "will" with adding animation is exactly what you should do

Comment: I actually only resize the UIView frame when the form is first loaded, just to reduce it's size from the standard height of a screen, as set by IB.  All of the changes that happen when the keyboard is shown/hidden are achieved by resizing the UIScrollView (using setContentSize).  Do you know what I should be researching to animate this resize?  Or do your earlier comments still apply?